# Question about $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin x dx = 1$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, distribution-theory

I saw that physicists use the following integral 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin x dx = 1
$$
in a distribution sense, i.e. 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin x dx := \lim_{a\to 0} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax}\sin x dx = \lim_{a\to 0} \frac{1}{a^{2}+1} = 1
$$
However, I wonder we get the same value when we change the distribution part. For example, we have the following result (according to Wolfram alpha)
$$
\lim_{a\to 0} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^{2}}\sin x dx = \lim_{a\to 0}\frac{F\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)}{\sqrt{a}} = \lim_{a\to 0 }\frac{e^{-1/4a}}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}}e^{y^{2}}dy =1 
$$
where $F(x):=e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{y^{2}}dy$ is a Dawson's integral.

To show this, we have to show the following : suppose a function $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and the integral 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(a, x)\sin x dx
$$
converges for any $a\geq 0$. If $f(0, x)=0$ for all $x\geq 0$, we have
$$
\lim_{a\to 0} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(a, x)\sin x dx = 0
$$
It seems that we cannot use dominated convergence theorem since $\sin x\not\in L^{1}$. If the above statement is true, is there any other function than $\sin x$ which satisfies the property and can define the improper integral in this way?

Comment: The assumptions on $f$, as stated here, are too weak to prove this kind of result even for $\sin x$, let alone other functions. Assuming $f$ monotonically decreasing to $0$ wrt $x$ may be enough for functions like sine (i.e., those with bounded antiderivative). Integration by parts sometimes turns non-$L^1$ things into $L^1$.

Comment: @6'whitemale Is it possible to prove the statement with a stronger assumption on $f$?

Comment: Perhaps it is too late, but a very specific kind of answer can be found in [*this answer*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968568/regulating-int-0-infty-sin-x-mathrmd-x).

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you very much!